# python object not iterable error in function

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop, iterable

I have a simple function with the following

```
comdList = range(0,27)
for t, in comdList:
    print t
```

However it returns a in object not iterable error

outside the function it works fine. Whats going on??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
for t in comdList:
    print t
```

The extra comma after the `t` variable was causing the error, because of it Python thinks that the iterable is going to return a sequence of 1-tuples to unpack - for example: `((1,), (2,))` but instead it received an iterable of single elements.

Comment: @ Óscar López - oh the comma... duh it it always the most obvious things that you miss thanks

Comment: @Darran you're welcome! please don't forget to [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) this or any other answer that you find helpful, just click on the check mark to its left ;)

Comment: Actually, `for t, in comdList` would only work if `comdList` was a sequence of 1-tuples ( `(1,), (2,), ...` ), not a sequence of higher-dimension tuples.