# TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable

Tags: python, python-2.7

Until very recently this piece of code worked. I added a function for prompt the user for a file name and extension, then that didn't work so I resorted back to this version. Now when I try to run it, I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Code/Samples/Dates/2015-06-07/Large-Scale Data Parsing/Parser/Single_File_Multistep_Counter.py", line 53, in <module>
main()
  File "C:/Code/Samples/Dates/2015-06-07/Large-Scale Data Parsing/Parser/Single_File_Multistep_Counter.py", line 51, in main
writer(final_counts(intermediate_count))
  File "C:/Code/Samples/Dates/2015-06-07/Large-Scale Data Parsing/Parser/Single_File_Multistep_Counter.py", line 31, in final_counts
for file_path in intermediate_file_list:
TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable
```

I'm nor completely sure what the error means, and after researching I could only find [python object not iterable error in function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17226331/python-object-not-iterable-error-in-function) and [python3 TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22633530/python3-typeerror-function-object-is-not-iterable) which do not solve my problem.

Below is the code giving me the error:

```
def final_counts(intermediate_file_list):
    date_list = {}
    for file_path in intermediate_file_list:
        with open(file_path, "r") as f:
            for line in f:
                tockens = line.split(",")
                if tockens[0] in date_list:
                    date_list[tockens[0]] = date_list[tockens[0]] + tockens[1]
                else:
                    date_list[tockens[0]] = tockens[1]
    return date_list
```

If needed, I will post the full code in a later edit. Any detailed answer explaining what I need to change would be very helpful, I want to learn the language and what I am doing wrong so (hopefully) later I won't make the same mistake.

**Edit:** Here is the entirety of my code

```
import os, glob, csv

location = "C:/Code/Samples/Dates/2015-06-07/Large-Scale Data Parsing/Data Files"
columnname = "smcn"
timecolumn = ""
filetype = ".processed"

def intermediate_count(location, filetype):
    intermediate_file_list = []
    for file_path in list(glob.glob(os.path.join(location, "*" + filetype))):
        date_list = {}
        print file_path
        with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
            for line in f:
                tockens = line.split(",")
                key = tockens[9] + "/" + tockens[15][:-4] #replace col_positon to 9 if necessary
                if key in date_list:
                    date_list[key] = date_list[key] + 1
                else:
                    date_list[key] = 1
        with open(file_path + ".count", "w") as csv:
            for item in date_list:
                csv.write(item + "," + str(date_list[item]) + "\n")
        intermediate_file_list.append(file_path + ".count")
    return intermediate_file_list

def final_counts(intermediate_file_list):
    date_list = {}
    for file_path in intermediate_file_list:
        with open(file_path, "r") as f:
            for line in f:
                tockens = line.split(",")
                if tockens[0] in date_list:
                    date_list[tockens[0]] = date_list[tockens[0]] + tockens[1]
                else:
                    date_list[tockens[0]] = tockens[1]
    return date_list

def writer(date_list):
    directory = location + "/" + "Total"
    if not os.path.exists(directory):
        os.makedirs(directory)
    with open(directory + "/" + "Total.processed", "w") as f: # Lots of commas!
        writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        for key, value in date_list.items():
            writer.writerow(str([key]) + str(value))

def main():
    writer(final_counts(intermediate_count))

main()
```

Comment: `final_counts` is being passed a function instead of an iterable. Can you show the code that is calling `final_counts`?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I will post it in just one second.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Shot in the dark:

`intermediate_count` is a helper function you made that returns an iterable.

Solution (if my guess was correct), you need to call the function `()`, otherwise as written you are passing the function object itself,  which is what the error is telling you

```
writer(final_counts(intermediate_count(location, filetype)))
                                      ^
```

Comment: Bingo! I need to wait a few minutes to accept your answer, but thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Change your `main` function to read like so:

```
def main():
    writer(final_counts(intermediate_count(location, filetype))
```

---

*Alternatively*, you could write it this way:

```
def main():
    writer(final_counts(intermediate_count())
```

And then change this:

```
def intermediate_count(location, filetype):
```

To this instead:

```
def intermediate_count():
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but Cory's works quite well. I need to keep the location and filetype outside of the intermediate count function when I start prompting for user input (continual repetition of input rejection until a "good" value is entered).